# Best practices for plugin service/controller/etc file names

Tags: plugin-development

When it comes to naming files within a plugin - is it preferable to follow `PluginHandle_SomeController`, or stuff everything inside a single `PluginHandleController` file?

This is probably a subjective question for the most part - but in building out a plugin at the moment, I have 4 different Service files, and I'm not sure if I'm being too pragmatic by breaking each different service type out individually, or if I should just include it within the single file. Each service isn't complex, they're basically a function or two each, but cover different aspects of the plugins feature set.

Any benefit to one way or the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of the day, it all comes down to **personal preference**. Depending on how large and/or complex each of your Service files is, it may make sense to break them up into separate files. Or if you've got less than a dozen service methods total, you could easily combine them into a single service file (if you choose).

For me personally, I try to break it up by where those service methods are being called from. `MyPlugin_VariableService` and `MyPlugin_ControllerService` for example... and any methods that are shared would go in the "main" `MyPluginService` file.

But every developer (and project) is different. You may have some other method of organizing that's better suited to you. So mostly personal preference.

---

However, the one thing I would definitely suggest... If you build any service methods which you'd like to be triggered from **other plugins**, then you may want to put those in your main service file. So the other plugins could simply call it like this:

```
craft->myPlugin->myMethod();
```

As far as an API for your plugin goes, it's much cleaner. Similarly, for any Controller actions which submit through a front-end form, you may want to have those submit through the "main" controller:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin/myAction">
```

Lastly, the same thinking applies to your main Variable file:

```
{{ craft.myPlugin.myVariable }}
```

Just makes for a cleaner interface for end-users and other devs. :)